# What does this statement "unit L2 norm" mean?

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, standardization, data-preprocessing

While I am reading the lars paper I encountered this statement " Note that these data are first standardized to have zero mean and unit L2 norm before they are used in the examples."

What does it mean for the data to have unit L2 norm ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The $L_2$ norm is $\lVert x \rVert = \sqrt{x^T x} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^d x_i^2}$. "Unit $L_2$ norm" means that for each data point $x$, $\lVert x \rVert = 1$. You can normalize a vector $x$ by just taking $\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}$.